# Angular2 - TypeError: this.http.get(...).toPromise is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

i try to follow tutorial on angular.io ([Tour the Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html))
But instead of tutorial I try to make real GET request on some JSON.

My code looks like:

```
  private userUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getUsersHttp(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.userUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as User[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

To service I import just few basic things:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { User } from './user';
```

Where `user.ts` is basicly copy of `heroe.ts` in TOH so:

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

How I call this specific method in service:
First I try multiple things but while debugging i try just console.log it so:

```
 console.log(this.userService.getUsersHttp());
```

When page is loading in console i found multiple errors:
First one is:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.http.get(...).toPromise is not a function

Second one is:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.http.get(...).toPromise is not a
>   functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @

Service it self looks fine. I added my service to `app.module.ts` in this line:

```
providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS, UserService ]
```

and it works if I directly return data with some function like (and comment out calling `getUsertHttp` function):

```
  getUsers() {
    return [{'id': 1, 'name': 'User1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'User2'}];
  }
```

I try to describe everything which may be important so sorry if question is kind long a bit. 
**Please guys can you give me hint what i am doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you also paste index.html and main.ts? Maybe missing core-js or es6-shim in polyfill.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Looks like you are missing import:

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';`

Comment: Hi @Stefan Svrkota, you were right i missed that import. I will mark your question as correct anyway but maybe any hint why `this.httpUsers` is undifined?
    `this.userService
      .getUsersHttp()
      .then(users => this.httpUsers = users)
      .catch(error => this.error = error);`

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users returns a json array, not an object which would have a .data member

Comment: Thank you both guys, Philippe was right about this,

Comment: Glad you fixed it.

Comment: The strange thing is that it worked for me for a few weeks without this import. Then, eventually, it stopped working, god knows why.