# Karma/Jasmine Testing Angular 2 Service Not Executing Code Inside Inject

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-services, ngrx

I am trying to test my Angular 2 service, which uses Observables and the ngrx Store. I have most tests passing but in one of my tests I am trying to mock the HTTP call, which I believe I am doing correctly but my issue is that none of my code in the "inject" statement is actually executing:

```
@Injectable()
export class FirmService {
  public stateObservable: Observable<FirmState>;

   constructor(private $http: AuthHttp, private store: Store<FirmState>) {
    // whatever reducer is selected from the store (in line below) is what the "this.store" refers to in our functions below.
    // it calls that specific reducer function
    this.stateObservable = this.store.select('firmReducer');
 }

public getFirms(value?: string) {
    return this.$http.get('/api/firm').map((response: Response) => {
        this.store.dispatch({
            type: firmActions.GET_FIRMS,
            payload: response.json()
        });
        return;
    });
   }
}
```

My Test for getFirms:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpModule, AppModule],
        providers: [
            { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
            FirmService
        ]
    }));


    // using these mock firms in other tests as well
    firms = {
        firms: [
            {
                'name': 'ICBC', 'country': 'United States', 'industry': 'Financial Services',
                'edfModels': [{ 'name': 'US FIN 4.0', 'QO': false }, { 'name': 'US FIN 4.0', 'QO': true }],
                'lgdModels': [{ 'name': 'US FIN 4.0', 'QO': false }, { 'name': 'US FIN 4.0', 'QO': true }],
                'modifiedOn': '1/1/2016', 'modifiedBy': 'John Doe'
            },

            {
                'name': 'CCBC', 'country': 'United States', 'industry': 'Financial Services',
                'edfModels': [{ 'name': 'US FIN 4.0', 'QO': false }, { 'name': 'US FIN 4.0', 'QO': true }],
                'lgdModels': [{ 'name': 'US FIN 4.0', 'QO': false }, { 'name': 'US FIN 4.0', 'QO': true }],
                'modifiedOn': '1/1/2016', 'modifiedBy': 'John Doe', 'selected': true
            }
        ]
   };
});

it('getFirms should dispatch the GET_FIRMS action', inject([FirmService, XHRBackend], (firmServiceMock, mockBackend) => {
     const expectedAction = {
        type: firmActions.GET_FIRMS,
        payload: firms
      };

       mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
             connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
                    body: JSON.stringify(firms)
            });
        }));

       spyOn(mockStore, 'dispatch');

       firmServiceMock.getFirms().subscribe(() => {
            expect(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedAction);

       });
 }));
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to remove this error in my spec file:
TypeError: http.get(...).map(...).toPromise is not a function.

It shouldn't be executing that http call in my service should it if I'm mocking it??

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have all of the dependencies, I can't verify this, but I believe you need to do the inject before the it block, as in a beforeEach.

Comment: thanks..looks like I had to move it up to the actual it declaration..I updated my code but now I am getting this error: " TypeError: http.get(...).map(...).toPromise is not a function" when it gets to my firmServiceMock.getFirms().subscribe line of code. I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121286/angular2-typeerror-this-http-get-topromise-is-not-a-function. But when I add that the error stops but no code runs inside my subscribe function. I've added the service I'm testing as well. Thanks