# Angular dynamic highchart integration - response is not updating in the chart component

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have integrated one simple highchart with angular. The data is coming from a below mock json which is created locally.

```
{
"title": "Mothly Average RainFall",
"subtitle": "Source: WorldClimate.com"
}
```

below is my chart component

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, 
ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { chart } from 'highcharts';
import { ChartServiceService } from '../chart-service.service';


@Component({
selector: 'app-barchart',
 templateUrl: './barchart.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./barchart.component.css'],
 providers: [ChartServiceService]
})
export class BarchartComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, 
 OnDestroy {
 resData: any;
 @ViewChild('barChartId') barChartId: ElementRef;
chart: Highcharts.ChartObject;

 constructor(private chartService: ChartServiceService) { }

getJsonData() {
this.chartService.getData()
.then(response => {
  this.resData = response;
  console.log(this.resData.title);
})
.catch(err => err)
 }

ngOnInit() {
this.getJsonData();
 }

ngAfterContentInit() {
const barChart: Highcharts.Options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
    },
  title: {
    text: this.resData.title
    },
  subtitle: {
    text: this.resData.subtitle
    },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 
 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    crosshair: true
    },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
     }
    },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
     }
    },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 
  194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 
 106.6, 92.3]

  }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 
51.2]

  }, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 
51.1]

  }]
};

this.chart = chart(this.barChartId.nativeElement, barChart);
  }

 ngOnDestroy() {
   this.chart = null;
 }

}
```

I get the response json data in resData and while accessing the title in the chart component I'm getting error saying cannot read property of undefined. Anyone knows the issue. The same I'm getting in console.log.

The chart service code I've updated below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChartServiceService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

// function to get the api response and convert to json
   private getResponseData(res: Response) {
   return res.json();
  }

  //function to handle the error from api call
  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
 console.error(error.message || error);
return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
 }

//function to get the response data using promise
public getData(): Promise<any> {
return this.http.get('assets/mockData.json').toPromise()
  .then(this.getResponseData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
 }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your `ChartServiceService` file? I am guessing something is going on where you aren't returning the simple object incorrectly. Also, I don't think many people do this, but you could do `resData: {title, subtitle};` so that you know what will be in the object.

Comment: @rhavelka: I have added the service code above.

Comment: Please try to debug the source of the "`error saying cannot read property of undefined`".  Also a live demo would be nice - for Angular you could use Plunker or codesandbox.io or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121286/angular2-typeerror-this-http-get-topromise-is-not-a-function) on http promises. Maybe your return statement should be

```
return this.http.get('assets/mockData.json').toPromise()
  .then(response => this.getResponseData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

But I am not 100% sure. Try doing `console.log(response)` to see if you are getting anything back, and if you accessing your object correctly. All of my responses are structured as response.body as having the data, but our services are set up very differently than mine.